# How to combine correlated signals?

Tags: signals, combinations, correlation

There are 11 signals:

- S_main : The original signal
- S1 ~ S10 : 10 signals that are correlated to S_main with different correlation coefficients (coeff1 ~ coeff10)

*Now here's the question:*

**How can I combine signals S1, S2, ..., S10 in order to generate S_main !!?**

(The correlation is not necessarily linear.)

Thanks a billion for your upcoming help.

Comment: Can you give an example or test case of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I said, I want to combine and mix signals S1 ~ S10 in order to generate S_main.

Comment: Isn't there anyone to answer !?

Comment: You have said that S1-S10 are correlated to S_main, but you have said the correlation is not necessarily linear.  Without an example or test case it is impossible to answer your question.  If you understand the problem, then you should be able to construct a simple test case or example that explains the relationship.  If you can not do that, then you probably need to do some research and ask the source of that problem for more info in order to discover what that relationship is.

Comment: Thanks Bob for your comment. (1) I said "not necessarily linear" because of the algorithms used. (Pearson, Spearsman, Kendall). (2) The relationship is much like similarity. Imagine for example that these are some potential signals, something like ECG. And they are very much similar to each other in terms of frequency, beating, ...